# Scala - groupBy keys of a map

Tags: scala, oop, group-by, maps

So i have a simple Map of type `Map [Long,Int]`.

My key in map are of type timestamp as below  (1446462630,1446462640,1446462650) are the keys of my map.

```
1446462630 = which is 11/02/2015 11:10:30(Epoch time in sceonds)
1446462640 = which is 11/02/2015 11:10:40(..)
1446462650 = which is 11/02/2015 11:10:50(..)
```

My map is as follows

```
1446462630->2
1446462640->1
1446462650->3
```

so now i want to display the accumulated count result grouped by minute between 11:10 and 11:11 so my output will be

```
1446462600 -> 6
```

1446462600(minute converstion of 11/02/2015 11:10)
how can i achive this? 
P.S i tried `myMap.groupBy{ _._1 / (60))` it does not work? Any suggestions on how to implement this in scala?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost there:

```
myMap.groupBy{ _._1 / (60)).map {case (sec, map) => sec -> map.values.sum}
```

Also consider TimeUnit usage for conversions. For your case:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(_._1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer similar to that of nyavro but with filters for your case.

```
myMap.groupBy(_._1/60).filterKeys(key => 
     key >= 1446462600/60 && key <= 1446462600/60+60
).map{
  case (k, v) => k*60 -> v.map(_._2).sum
}

res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1446462600 -> 6)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working perfectly now. i was missing the sum of values after grouping.